# How to allow code-folding on Geany IDE?

Tags: ide, syntax-highlighting, folding, geany

Is there any way to fold all of functions at one time on Geany IDE?

Is there any way to do that?

I am looking for any option which let my Geany IDE to fold all of the functions at one time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Document -> Fold All`.

Answer (score 2):

### One may pre-configure Geany shortcuts for (un)-folding as needed:

**Enter** 
<kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`Alt`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`P`**</kbd> *to open a Geany* **`[Preferences]`** *settings UI-panel*

**Select** **`[Keyboard Keybindings]`** tab on the left,

**Scroll** down to section **`[+][Document]`** and **unfold** it's attribute settings

**Setup** an unused keyboard shortcut for each of, as handy:
**`- Toggle Folding On/Off on a current code-block`**
**`- Unfold the whole document`**
**`- Fold the whole document`**

> <sub>( **prompts** are not exact, actual Geany language-localisation may provide other expressions while **meaning** is clear )</sub>

---

### One may pre-configure Geany to enable / disable (un)-folding + details:

**Enter** 
<kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`Alt`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`P`**</kbd> *to open a Geany* **`[Preferences]`** *settings UI-panel*

**Select** **`[Editor]`** tab on the left,

(un)-**Check** selection boxes as preferred in:
**`[x] Enable folding`**
**`[x] Fold/Unfold all children of a fold point`** ... a <kbd>**`[Shift]+<aMouseCLICK>`**</kbd> is interpreted as a one-shot reversed setting of this preferences attribute